# Find rows whose values are less/greater than rows of another dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'begin': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                     'end': [15, 23, 36, 48, 56]})
   begin  end
0     10   15
1     20   23
2     30   36
3     40   48
4     50   56

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'begin2': [12, 13, 22, 40],
                      'end2': [14, 13, 26, 48]})
   begin2  end2
0      12    14
1      13    13
2      22    26
3      40    48
```

How can i get the rows of df2 which are within the rows of df1? I want each row of the df2 to be compared to all rows of df1.

That is, i want a df3 like:

```
   begin2  end2
0      12    14
1      13    13
3      40    48
```

I tried:

```
df3 = df2.loc[ (df['begin'] <= df2['begin2']) & (df2['end2'] <= df['end'] )]
```

But it only compares row for row and requeres same sizes of the dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df2[df2.apply(lambda x: any((df['begin'] <= x['begin2']) & 
                                 (x['end2'] <= df['end'])), axis=1)]
print (df)
   begin2  end2
0      12    14
1      13    13
3      40    48
```

Detail:

```
print (df2.apply(lambda x: any((df['begin'] <= x['begin2']) & 
                               (x['end2'] <= df['end'])), axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```